# how to create template class in another class with out default constructor

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following template class

```
template <typename threadFuncParamT >
class ThreadPool
{
    // number of threads to be launced initially and added to thread pool.
    ThreadPool( pThreadFunc pFunction, RtsInt16_t minThreads, RtsInt16_t maxThreads, RtsInt16_t maxExecCount);
};
```

Now i want to use object of another class

```
struct myStruct 
    //...
};

class MyClass 
{
private:

    ThreadPool<myStruct *> pool;
};
```

My question is how to create `ThreadPool` with constructor arguments in MyClass constructor as I don't have default constructor?

Comment: Despite your latest edit, your question is still unclear, because you still don't explain which class you are referring to as missing a default constructor. That's why I had to answer for the two possibilities I saw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean "as I don't have default constructor in `ThreadPool`:

```
MyClass::MyClass()
 : pool( &thrdFunc, 7, 42, 12 )
{
}
```

Assuming you mean "as I don't have default constructor in `MyClass`:

`MyClass` has a default constructor as long as you either provide your own or you do not provide any other constructor. As it is in your question, it has a compiler-generated default constructor. Of course, that wouldn't compile, because the compiler-generated default constructor would simply call the default constructors of all (base classes and) data members, and the only data member `pool` is of a class that doesn't provide a default constructor.
So you need to provide your own default constructor, as shown in the example above.

Answer (score 1):

Like any other member -- this is not specific to template instantiation types -- in the initializer list for the constructors of MyClass. For instance for the default constructor:.

```
MyClass::MyClass()
   : pool(myFunction, myMinThread, myMaxThread, myExeCount)
{}
```